# Does moving counters "put" counters on destination?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm particularly trying to figure what interaction there is between [Shalai and Hallar](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=612088) and [Forgotten Ancient](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=612545).

Specifically, Forgotten Ancient says during my upkeep I may move counters to another creature.  Moving doesn't require targeting, so I wanted to make sure that it won't run afoul of other situations too.  If I move counters from Forgotten Ancient to another creature, will that count as putting the counters on the second creature and thus trigger the damage ability of Shalai and Hallar?

Similarly, I assume [Branching Evolution](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=489196) would see it the same way and would let me double the number of moved counters and then do the damage, correct?

I presume so, but I want to make sure of that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Yes, moving counters puts counters on an object.**

This is stated in [rule 122.5](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Counter_(marker)):

> If an effect says to “move” a counter, it means to remove that counter from the object it’s currently on and put it onto a second object. [...]

This means that it will trigger any effect that checks for counters being put on objects such as Shalai and Hallar, and any ability that modifies counters being put on an object will modify that event, such as Branching Evolution.

Answer (score 9):

**Yes, they will count as being put onto their new object.**

Moving counters is covered in the Comprehensive Rules under **122.5**, which reads as follows:

> **122.5.** If an effect says to “move” a counter, it means to remove that counter from the object it’s currently on and put it onto a second object. If either of these actions isn’t possible, it’s not possible to move a counter, and no counter is removed from or put onto anything. This may occur if the first and second objects are the same object; if the first object doesn’t have the appropriate kind of counter on it; if the second object can’t have counters put onto it; or if either object is no longer in the correct zone.